# Android variable dependant on time

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My data class model in my Android project has a variable lets call it value.

> data class Person(name : String = "", value : Int = 0){
> }

I would like for variable value of type Int to decrease over time. Lets say it decreases everyday by 1. So if it is 10 today, tomorrow it will be 9, the day after 8 etc etc even if my app is "dead"/not opened. How should I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a timestamp given in `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Then, in the future, count the days that passed since that timestamp:

```
(System.currentTimeMillis() - value) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS
```

If you want the number to decrease, let's say from 10, it'll be:

```
10 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - value) / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS
```

Enjoy :)